# Как разделить функционал администратора от клиента в приложении?

Tags: android, архитектура

Есть идея создать мобильное приложение для взаимодействия клиентов с администратором, как отделить функционал админа от клиента? тобишь и клиент и администратор
Устанавливают одно приложение в котором есть клиентская и админ часть , клиенту не доступна админ часть?

Comment: Администраторским паролем, а лучше два приложения. Можно делать два билда из одного проекта.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja согласен со вторым предложением, лучше делать два билда, отдельно для администратора, отдельно для пользователя.

Comment: Не удобно получается, клинт одну сборку качает админ - другую. А так одну приложуху скачал, просто у админа расширенные возможности. Думал сделать при регистрации пункт где указывается пользователь: админ или клиент

Comment: @ВиталийСупрун, все-равно, вам будет нужна проверка, чтобы пользователи не получили права администратора. У вас наверняка будет база с сервером, где будут пользователи. Там можно хранить роль (пользователь, администратор и т.п.) или булевый флаг (типа `is_admin`). При авторизации пользователя по логину можно будет определить его полномочия

Comment: @gil9red я могу при регистрации создать пункт где указывается роль : клиент или администратор. После чего уже предоставлять функционал